# Rebooting a server after Windows application is installed using Python

Tags: python, windows

I am developing some Python (version 3.6.1) code to install an application in Windows 7. The code used is this:

```
winCMD = r'"C:\PowerBuild\setup.exe" /v"/qr /l C:\PowerBuild\TUmsi.log"'
output = subprocess.check_call(winCMD, shell = True)
```

The application is installed successfully. The problem is that it always requires a reboot after it is finished (a popup with a message "You must restart your system for the configuration changes made to  to take effect. Click Yes to restart now or No if you plan to restart later.).

I tried to insert parameter "/forcerestart" ([source here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx)) in the installation command but it still stops to request the reboot:

```
def installApp():
    winCMD = r'"C:\PowerBuild\setup.exe" /v"/qr /forcerestart /l C:\PowerBuild\TUmsi.log"'
    output = subprocess.check_call(winCMD, shell = True)
```

Another attempt was to create a following command like this one below, although since the previous command is not finished yet (as per my understanding) I realized it will never be called:

```
rebootSystem = 'shutdown -t 0 /r /f'
subprocess.Popen(rebootSystem, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Does anyone had such an issue and could solve it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to Python, as all you're doing is executing some Windows commands (via `subprocess`)

Comment: A workaround would be to get the dialog window handle (for that in order to make things easier you would need [_pywin32_](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32)) and send it an event making it think that the user pressed _OK_. But you would need to do that in a separate thread (as the main one would be blocked by `subprocess.Popen`). And if this is OK, you could replace the `shutdown` command, by an _WinAPI_ call,

Comment: Thank you CristiFati for your comment. Actually I thought initially to get through pywin32 but, from my point of view, it would be too much code for "only" a reboot, so I was trying other approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an ugly workaround, if you're not time-critical but you want to emphasise the "automatic" aspect, why not

- run the `installCMD` in a thread
- wait sufficiently long to be sure that the command has completed
- perform the shutdown

like this:

```
import threading,time
def installApp():
    winCMD = r'"C:\PowerBuild\setup.exe" /v"/qr /l C:\PowerBuild\TUmsi.log"'
    output = subprocess.check_call(winCMD, shell = True)

t = threading.Thread(target=installApp)
t.start()
time.sleep(1800)  # half-hour should be enough
rebootSystem = 'shutdown -t 0 /r /f'
subprocess.Popen(rebootSystem, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Another (safer) way would be to find out which file is created last in the installation, and monitor for its existence in a loop like this:

```
while not os.path.isfile("somefile"):
     time.sleep(60)
time.sleep(60)  # another minute for safety
# perform the reboot
```

To be clean, you'd have to use `subprocess.Popen` for the installation process, export it as global and call `terminate()` on it in the main process, but since you're calling a `shutdown` that's not necessary.

(to be clean, we wouldn't have to do that hack in the first place)

Comment: Despite being an "ugly workaround" the thread approach worked as expected. This was I learned how to use - in a simple way - threading which I did not know before. Maybe a more beautiful workaround raises from this study :)